# How to trigger handlers in angular ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a repeater with 2 click handlers inside (on an icon and on a span). When I click on the **span** I want to trigger the **icon**. I only achieved to select and trigger the first element in the repeater (in the first li). I'm having trouble selecting the current clicked element in the repeater.

[Live demo](http://codepen.io/ptongalex/pen/eZLMGJ)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="tree-list"">
 <li ng-repeat="stuff">
   <i ng-click="stuff"></i>
   <div>
     <span ng-click="forceClickTheIconAbove"></span>
   </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
// works
el = angular.element('.tree-list li:first-child i:first-child');
// output: el = [i.tree-branch-head.glyphicon.glyphicon-triangle-top, i.tree-branch-head.glyphicon.glyphicon-triangle-top, prevObject: init[1], context: document, selector: ".tree-list li:first-child i:first-child"]
el.click();

// not working
el = angular.element(".tree-list li")[0].children[0];
// output: el = <i ng-click="doStuff()">
el.click();
```

Comment: are u using jquery to handle click or ng-click , im confused here . if your using jquery its outside angular world , so u need to use $scope.$digest or $apply

Comment: Could you provide a demo? At a high level, you may want to look at passing the event, such as ng-click=clickFunction($event). Then, you can look at the target of the event, and do something with preventDefault().

Comment: @BrianS: done, updated

Comment: @Shushanth Pallegar: I had some errors with $digest if I don't user $timeout, I user triggerHandler('click') also...and didn't work

Comment: @ShushanthPallegar : it s working now with the triggerHandler method...thanks for the hint. How can I evade $digest and $apply errors ?

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your question, so I made a little example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5028/

You can track the clicked li with `$index`

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {    
  $scope.forceClickTheIconAbove = function(item) {
    var el = angular.element(".tree-list li")[item].children[0];
    console.log(el);
    // output: el = <i ng-click="doStuff()">
    el.click();
  }
}
```

And in your HTML:

```
<ul class="tree-list" ng-repeat="s in stuff">
    <li>{{s.name}}
      <i class={{s.name}}>Icon</i>
      <div>
        <span ng-click="forceClickTheIconAbove($index)">Click here to trigger icon</span>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```